# Conditional probability the of Sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables such that $X>a$ and $a<X+Y<b$. Please how do I simplify further, the conditional probability $\Pr(a <X+Y <b \Big| X>a) $ $~$ ? I am guessing that one of the final terms will involve convolution of the sum $X+Y$, but I don't know how to go about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is $\frac {\int_{(a, \infty)} [F_Y((b-x)-)-F_Y(a-x)] dF_X(x)} {\int_{(a, \infty)} dF_X(x)}$.

[ Write $\{a<X+Y<b, X>a\}$ as $\{a-X<Y<b-X, X>a\}$, conidition on $X$ and then  integrate].

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ have densities, say $f$ and $g$ then the expression becomes $\frac {\int_a^{\infty} \int_{a-x}^{b-x} g(y)dy f(x) dx} {\int_a^{\infty} f(x)dx}$.

Comment: If the range of $X$ is $X>a$, isn't the conditional probability just equal to the non conditional probability?

Comment: @dfnu I don 't think OP really meant that $X>a$ and $a <X+Y<b$ hold with probability $1$. The question is too trivial in this case.